# Disabling dates in jQuery Date Picker based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a date picker and its contained in the following code:

`<input type="text" class="input-text  hasDatepicker" name="myfld1" id="myfld1" placeholder="Select the delivery date" value="">`

I have another select field with named Days with Monday and Wednesday with the code:

```
<select name="myfield2" id="myfield2" class="select ">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select    below</option>
<option value="Mondays">Mondays</option>
<option value="Wednesdays">Wednesdays</option>
</select>
```

What i am trying to achieve is that, when Monday is selected, the date picker should only show dates that fall on Monday and similarly for Wednesday.

Below is the jQuery code i am using:

```
 deliverydate = {
    init: function () {
        jQuery('#myfld1').datepicker("option", "minDate", +1);
        jQuery('#myfld1').datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", this.disabledays);
    },
    disabledays: function (date) {
        return [(date.getDay() == jQuery('#myfield2').val())];
    }
};

deliverydate.init(),
        b.init(),
        c.init(),
        d.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code does the work:

### Markup

```
<p>Date:
    <input type="text" name="myfld1" id="myfld1" placeholder="Select the delivery date" value="">
</p>
<select name="myfield2" id="myfield2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select below</option>
    <option value="1">Mondays</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesdays</option>
</select>
```

### jQuery/JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#myfld1').datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: function() {
             return [false];
         }
     });
     $("#myfield2").on('change', function() {
         var showDayOn = this.value;
         $('#myfld1').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function (date) {
             return [date.getDay() == showDayOn];
         });
     });
 });
```

### Live

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jithin4u/w7PHj/122/)